# Value is not updating with custom select component

Tags: vue.js, user-interface, vuejs2, v-model

I have one component with the following code:

```js
<template>
  <select
    class="
      py-1.5
      px-2
      outline-none
      border-primary-lightblue border-2
      rounded-xl
      transition
      duration-500
      focus:border-primary-blue
    "
  >
    <option
      v-for="option in optionsWithDefaultState"
      :key="option.value || option"
      :value="option.value || option"
      :selected="(option.value || option) === defaultValue"
      :disabled="option === ' '"
      :hidden="option === ' '"
    >
      {{ option.label || option }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  model: {
    prop: "value",
    event: "change",
  },
  props: {
    options: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
    defaultValue: {
      type: [Object, String],
      default: " ",
    },
  },
  computed: {
    optionsWithDefaultState() {
      return [" ", ...this.options];
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style></style>
```

and when I use it with the following code it works

```js
                   <v-dropdown
                        :value="teacherId"
                        :options="teachers"
                        @change.native="
                          (val) => {
                            teacherId = val.target.value;
                          }
                        "
                      ></v-dropdown>
```

but with this it doesn't, and I can't figure out why

```js
                      <v-dropdown
                        v-model="teacherId"
                        :options="teachers"
                      ></v-dropdown>
```

In vue docs it says that the code above will be transpiled to the second code I have here, but it still is not working.

Comment: What happens with the 2nd example? Can you be more explicit?

Comment: it works as expected, the value updates

Answer (score 0):

You're not emitting any event from your component. Because of this, v-model watches for `change` events that come in, but those events are never emitted by your component, so nothing happens.

```html
<select
    class="
      ...
    "
    @change="$emit('change', $event)"
  >
```